# How to customize angular material components

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, vertical-alignment, font-size

I am trying to build a simple and responsive register form using angular material. I have tried to change height of the input for bigger screens so it will be more visible and everything broke.

- I can't align `mat-icon` and `mat-label` in the center
- Ripple effect for `mat-icon` button is misaligned
- I can't change button's font-size as long as this button has `mat-raised-button` attribute

How can I customize these elements? I can't find anything in angular material docs and at this point I feel like making everything from scratch without angular material and its fancy stuff. But maybe I didn't go through their site as thoroughly as I should.
I have tried the most obvious things like: `font-size`, using flexbox, `vertical-align` but none worked for me.

---

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-field">
  <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
  <mat-icon matPrefix>lock_outline</mat-icon>
  <input
    matInput
    formControlName="password"
    [errorStateMatcher]="semiStrictMatcher"
    [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
  />
  <button
    mat-icon-button
    matSuffix
    (click)="hide = !hide"
    [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
    [attr.aria-pressed]="hide"
    type="button"
  >
    <mat-icon>{{ hide ? "visibility_off" : "visibility" }}</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

**CSS:**

```
   @media screen and (min-width: 2500px) {
      .form-field {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        height: 200px;
        font-size: 40px;
        mat-icon {
          margin-right: 20px;
        }
        input {
          height: 80px; //<- this is the culprit - everything misaligned after this
        }
        mat-icon,
        mat-label,
        input {
          font-size: 45px;
        }
      }
   }
```

---

This is how it looks like as default (smaller screens):
[image: small screens example - good]

And this is what happend after I increased input heigh(larger screens):
[image: large screens example - bad]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize `mat-form-field` as below inside global `styles.scss` :

```
.custom-form-field {
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 40px;

  .mat-form-field-prefix {
    .mat-icon {
      font-size: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      line-height: 60px;
    }
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  .mat-form-field-suffix {
    button {
      .mat-icon {
        font-size: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 60px;
      }
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want to create a global style into `styles.scss` and want to use the component `scss`, you will have to set class name on `matPrefix` and `matSuffix` to correctly address them :

in component.html`

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="custom-form-field">
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <mat-icon matPrefix class="prefix">lock_outline</mat-icon>

    <input matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" />

    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix class="suffix" (click)="hide = !hide">
      <mat-icon>{{ hide ? "visibility_off" : "visibility" }}</mat-icon>
    </button>

  </mat-form-field>
```

in `component.scss`:

```
.custom-form-field {
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 40px;

  .mat-icon.prefix {
    font-size: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  button.suffix {
    .mat-icon {
      font-size: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      line-height: 60px;
    }
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
```